# Can't change Formview mode on GridView_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

I want my **Formview** to start in **Insert mode** and then change to **Edit mode** when a user selects a row from the **Gridview** in the same page.

The Formview has the inline attribute: **DefaultMode="Insert"**

How can this be done and why isn't this working?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)   
{   
    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
}
```

Edit1: 
FormView Source code

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="AdID" DataSourceID="AdByID" DefaultMode="Insert">
<EditItemTemplate>
    Caption:
    <asp:TextBox ID="CaptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Caption") %>' />
    <br />
    Summary:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Text:
    <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" Runat="server" Content='<%# Bind("Text") %>' ToolsFile="~/crm/annonser/ToolsFile.xml"  
        Language="sv-SE" ToolbarMode="Default" 
        AllowScripts="True" EditModes="Design" Skin="Office2007" 
        StripFormattingOnPaste="MSWord" Width="500px">
        <Content>
        </Content>
    </telerik:RadEditor>
    <br />
    Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
    <br />
    Email:
    <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
    <br />
    Phone:
    <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>' />
    <br />
    PhoneHidden:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="PhoneHiddenCheckBox" runat="server" 
        Checked='<%# Bind("PhoneHidden") %>' />
    <br />
    Price:
    <asp:TextBox ID="PriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' />
    <br />
    CategoryCodeID:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="AdCategoryMarket" DataTextField="Caption" 
        DataValueField="AdCategoryCodeID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CategoryCodeID") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AdCategoryMarket" runat="server" 
        DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="dsCRMTableAdapters.app_AdCategoryCodeTableAdapter" 
        UpdateMethod="Update">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdCategoryCodeID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DisplayOrder" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryTypeID" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DisplayOrder" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryTypeID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdCategoryCodeID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <br />
    StateCodeID:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="AdStateCode" 
        DataTextField="Caption" DataValueField="AdStateCodeID" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StateCodeID") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AdStateCode" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" 
        InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="dsCRMTableAdapters.app_AdStateCodeTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdStateCodeID" Type="Byte" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdStateCodeID" Type="Byte" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <br />
    RegionCodeID:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Regions" 
        DataTextField="name" DataValueField="RegionCodeID" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("RegionCodeID") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Regions" runat="server" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="dsCRMTableAdapters.app_RegionCodeTableAdapter">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <br />
    StopDate:
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" Runat="server" Culture="sv-SE" 
        DbSelectedDate='<%# Bind("StopDate") %>'>
    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AdID") %>' />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
</EditItemTemplate></asp:FormView>
```

FormView DataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AdByID" runat="server"  
OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByID" 
TypeName="dsCRMTableAdapters.app_AdTableAdapter" DeleteMethod="Delete" 
InsertMethod="Insert" UpdateMethod="Update">
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdID" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Summary" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneHidden" Type="Boolean" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="StateCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="RegionCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="StopDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CreatedOn" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedOn" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="AdGUID" />
</InsertParameters>
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="AdID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Caption" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Summary" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneHidden" Type="Boolean" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="StateCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="RegionCodeID" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="StopDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CreatedOn" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedOn" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="AdGUID" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_AdID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

---

The data is updated as expected but no events seems to fire... the following redirect simply doesn't happen:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(Object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

The initial problem most likely resides from there, don't you think? The question is, how do I get the events to work as expected?

Comment: Could you please explain what are you meaning by "isn't working"?

Comment: Well, the form doesn't change to edit mode.

Comment: Are you binding assigning the datasource property of the FormView1 or you are using some kind of data source controls (like ObjectDataSource, SqlDataSource, XmlDataSource,...) ? Some code would be would be very helpful.

Comment: The FormView is using an ObjectDataSource with a SelectParameter collected from the GridView. I didn't realize datasource would have an impact on this matter...

Comment: In fact there is no problem with them if they are properly configured. Could you please post the code for ObjectDataSource and FormView1?

Comment: Code added as requested.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out what is the cause of you problem. I have only one advice that might help: try to use FormView1_ModeChanging for binding the FormView using it's DataSource property. In this way you will gain much more control over what is happening and will be able to debug eventual problems.

Comment: Could you point me in any direction on examples of how to use ModeChanging as you mentioned above?